How to add a spatially enabled df to a Leafmap map
Python: 3.9
ArcGIS API for Python: 2.3.0.1
I am accessing a Feature Layer from the Living Atlas using the ArcGIS API for Python. I convert it to a sdf with the column 'SHAPE' as the geometry. How do I add the sdf to a Leafmap map. I have added other layers to the map via add_gdf(). Can I convert the sdf to a gdf? I saw I could convert it to a local GeoJSON using this code (Converting ArcGIS Spatially Enabled Dataframe to GeoJSON). This is for a streamlit web application so I am not sure how I would connect to a local file.
Here is some of the code I am using:
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis import gis, GeoAccessor, geometry
gis = GIS()

def read_fl(item_id):
    living_atlas_item = gis.content.get(item_id)
    feature_layer = living_atlas_item.layers[0]
    sdf = feature_layer.query(where="1=1", out_sr=4326).sdf
    return sdf

item_id = "21638fcd54d14a25b6f1affdef812146"
sdf = read_fl(item_id)

# Transform sdf to gdf somehow

# Create map
map = leafmap.Map(
    layers_control=True,
    draw_control=False,
    measure_control=False,
    fullscreen_control=False)

map.add_basemap(basemap_selection)
map.add_gdf(
    gdf=sdf,
    zoom_to_layer=False,
    layer_name='Fires',
    info_mode='on_click',
    )


I found it to be simple than I thought.
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(sdf, geometry='SHAPE')

